# Metadata collection on messaging apps

Tags: privacy

I know some of the messaging apps out there do not collect metadata of the users, but can gov entities force companies operating the servers to collect metadata such as ip addresses of the communicating parties so pairing can be established?

Answer (score 1):

Every country treats it's citizens privacy differently. In general, some countries do have laws which allow collection of such data. In the United States national security letters (NSLs) have been sent to companies to request such data and in some cases more data than just the metadata. I'll also add that some of the metadata collection may also be handled at the ISP level such that a government could potentially request that the ISP's collect connection data but never approach the company directly. This is a very broad question and the answer is a bit different for every country and even within different branches of governments in those countries but some countries definitely have laws allowing them to request this type of data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_security_letter

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When choosing a messaging service. It is important to examine the technique used. One wants to use a service provider that can't collect metadata even if they are willing to do that. Bitmessage seems to be able to do that, but it has a scaling problem.